# List out accepted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I suggest to  have accepted options under answer tab, so we can check all the accepted answers written by us/users.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this is an important enough action for it to take up space in the profile.

If you really need to do this you should use the advanced search operator [`isaccepted:yes`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+user%3Ame).